# My discord.py music bot fails with "ffmpeg not found"

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I am using repl.it to host my Discord.py music bot
It fails with an error saying "ffmpeg is not found"
I used multiple ways to fix the error

npm install ffmpeg-static in shell is my first way how i tried to fix the problem, but it did not do anything.

Even if i do any way, repl.it will still give the error ffmpeg not found.
Can someone please tell any way to fix this issue??

Comment: I assume you based your bot on the official Discord.py Music Bot. Can you check if you have ffmpeg-static in your package-lock.json?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov i do have ffmpeg-static in my package-lock.json but for some reason it still shows the error "ffmepg not found"

Is this it?

{
  "name": "MusictestBot",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ffmpeg-static": "^5.0.0"
      }
    },

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg-static` npm package does not add `ffmpeg` to the system path. From documenatation:

> Returns the path of a statically linked ffmpeg binary on the local filesystem.

```
    var pathToFfmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');
    console.log(pathToFfmpeg);
```

```
    /Users/j/playground/node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg
```

Your issue arises from Python runtime not having this path in its system path. So, you need to get that `pathToFfmpeg` value and use it in your discord.py call, e.g.,

```py
discord.FFmpegAudio("input.wav", executable='/Users/j/playground/node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg')
```

The other alternative is to add this `/Users/j/playground/node_modules/ffmpeg-static` to the (run-time) system path using

```py
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + `/Users/j/playground/node_modules/ffmpeg-static`
```

There are alternates in Python, though. Namely, [`ffmpeg-static`](https://github.com/zackees/static_ffmpeg) or [`ffmpeg-downloader`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpeg-downloader) package (I'm the owner of the latter). They achieve the same end-goal but behave a bit differently. Either should work for your use-case if you choose to go this route.

**`static-ffmpeg`**

This one downloads the binaries inside its `Lib/site-packages` folder, and the downloading occurs during the first execution within your python script/app. The binaries it downloads are hosted by the package owner.

```
pip install static-ffmpeg
```

```py
from static_ffmpeg import run

ffmpeg, ffprobe = run.get_or_fetch_platform_executables_else_raise()
discord.FFmpegAudio("input.wav", executable=ffmpeg)
```

**`ffmpeg-downloader`**

This downloads to an external user folder (specified by `appdirs` package) and downloading is executed outside of python user script/app. It fetches the binaries directly from the hosts listed on FFmpeg website.

```
pip install ffmpeg-downloader
python -m ffmpeg_downloader
```

```py
import ffmpeg_downloader as ffdl

discord.FFmpegAudio("input.wav", executable=ffdl.ffmpeg_path)
```

Comment: I have did all of your methods. But it still shows FFMPEG is not found?
Maybe it is something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong, It still shows FFMPEG is not found..

This is my code :

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx, url):
  
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1-reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5","options":"-vn"}
  YDL_OPTIONS = {"format":"bestaudio"}
  vc = ctx.voice_client
  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    
    info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
    url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
    await ctx.send("Playing song")
    opusaudio = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    source = discord.FFmpegAudio(opusaudio, executable='/Users/j/playground/node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg')
    vc.play(source)
```

At all times, it shows "FFMPEG is not found" as an error.
I searched online and for repls in repl.it but none of them seems to work for me.
All it just shows is, "FFMPEG not found"
Can someone please do help me with this error??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).